# how can i call javascript on loading a page dynamically through ajax tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have a base file (`base.jsp`) which has included references to jquery.js, lightbox.js etc. This file has jquery tabs and URL specified in href.

example:

```
<div id="tabs" style="float:left; width:100%; clear:both;">
<ul>
    <li> <a href="HelloWorld.jsp"> Hello world tab </a></li>
    <li> <a href="OtherWorld.action?id=1"> Other world tab </a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

Let's assume `OtherWorld.action?id=1` => yields `Result2.jsp`

I'd like to attach function handlers to onClick event on certain divs that are found in `Result2.jsp`. I usually use something like this in Result2.jsp:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // attach event handlers here
}
```

However, I don't have access to jquery or other javascripts I included in base.jsp, so the above doesn't work.

**When loading html in tabs through ajax, where should I define the javascript that I'd like to be fired on load ?**

**Should I again include the external javascripts in Result2.jsp that I intend to use on Result2.jsp?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to include all your javascript in your main page, and when returning from the ajax if status==200 then call your javascript(JQuery functions)